What options does Bangladesh have to stop Sheikh Hasina from travelling using an Indian government supplied travel document?
Although Indian news outlets are maintaining a radio silence, Bangladeshi newspapers reported that the Indian government has supplied a travel document to Sheikh Hasina through which she left India and is now staying in the Ajman State of UAE.
What options does Bangladesh have to stop Sheikh Hasina from travelling using an Indian government-supplied travel document?
.

      
.

.
Note: Don't delete the above screenshots, as Bangladeshi newspapers regularly remove news articles because of their own political affiliations.

Out of curiosity:  how motivated is the Bangladeshi government, officially, to do get Hasina back?  I know she's been getting a lot of posts here, some pro, mostly against.  And it seems her government was indeed pretty dodgy and authoritarian at the end.  But India is a big neighbor to antagonize, and with Bangladesh it's either China or India (discounting Myanmar), so...

This question can probably be generalized to work without the specific person or countries. Just to make answers apply to many more cases.

Those screenshots we are not supposed to remove, do you have the copyright to post them here?

I am not sure how much country X has to say about travel documents issued by country Y to country X's citizens.  It would seem to me that depends entirely on how third party countries view Y's specific document, something X has little control over (what if Hasina got granted Indian citizenship and travelled on an Indian passport, for example).
Slotting in Bangladesh (small country), for X and India (big country) for Y makes things harder here.
Theoretically, however, if Bangladesh could convince the ICC to issue an arrest warrant for Hasina, then the game would change quite a bit.
Whether or not the ICC has cause to issue such a warrant in this case, whether the ICC would choose to do so, whether it is worthwhile for Bangladesh to pursue this route, and how long it would take is another story...
Another option is for Bangladesh to convince the UAE that hosting Hasina is too embarrassing.  Every so often you see exiled ex-leaders being asked to vacate a host country when their presence causes issues.  Trouble is that you need to start all over again with whomever accepts them next.  And the fact that they are accepted in the first place means that the host country doesn't value your concerns all that much.
Yet another option is to use an Interpol Red Notice.  That has indeed been done by some countries for political (not always good) reasons.  Those are fairly routinely ignored in this case, I believe and Interpol is not supposed to take on politically-motivated cases.
There may be others, but these are options I see.

These Interpol red notices are probably because of domestic arrest warrants? Anyway I guess that the second option won't work because India's clout is much stronger than that of Bangladesh.

Bangladesh has more inhabitants than Russia, Mexico, or Japan, and around twice that of Germany.  Not sure it counts as a small country, except when compared to India.

@gerrit - Bangladesh is a small country in terms of political and economic clout. It ranks 34th for GDP at $460 Billion putting it between Singapore and Vietnam.

@PaulSmith - So, only in the top 20% of countries, then?

@Obie2.0 - Being in the top 20% doesn't count for much when the Bangladeshi GDP is less than 0.5% of the number one economy, and less then 10 times the median economy of failed state Libya. Don't get me wrong, Bangladesh is a lovely country with lots of lovely people, it just does not have any significant political or economic influence.
